# When will btrfs-progs (stable??) arrive in the repositories?

Tags: btrfs

just realized that arch linux exchanged btrfs-progs-unstable (from 2010) with btrfs-progs (from 2012, presumably stable, at least not unstable). I am aware that arch is normally very quick at upgrading. When is this (or kind of) package expected to arrive in official ubuntu repos?

Thanks...

Comment: Next release if it gets packged before the freeze, and if they approve it.

Answer (score 1):

`btrfs-progs` is called `btrfs-tools` in Ubuntu (or any Debian based distro).

You can follow [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/btrfs-tools/+bug/894456) on Launchpad to stay informed about the package's status.

From the bug report you can see there's already a packaged version in Debian unstable, so this needs to be [merged](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/Merging) (ie., someone needs to step up and do it, but I got no info whether that's planned for Precise or not).